# Можно ли подключить С++ классы к проекту написанному на objective-c?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

У меня есть проект `XCode` написанный на `Objective-c` и некоторые классы, которые могут обрабатывать данные, написанные на `C++`.

**Вопрос:** можно ли к `XCode` проекту, подключить модули написанные на `С++`? И если да, то где почитать по этому вопросу?

Comment: Уверен, что можно.  А чем собираете свой xcode проект?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Просто нажимаю кнопку run и он сам собирается у меня на яблофоне.

Comment: да, можно и даже делал когда то подобное. Просто файлам, где код на с++ нужно давать расширение cpp и добавлять такие файлы как обычно.

Comment: так классы или модули? пробовали просто добавить в проект?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko мне бы простой класс С++ с одной функцией (пофигу возвращающей, или выводящей строку), и вызов этой функции из XCode проекта. И я был бы счастлив.

Comment: насколько я помню, вам надо .m переименовать в .mm, чтоб xcode знал, что это С, и вроде все. Либо создайте новый C файл в xcode, и в него скопируйте весь код

Comment: А я сегодня как только не переименовывал, и куча ошибок. Такие дела. Может какой-то фрэймворк включить нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можно. ".mm" файлы могут инклудить заголовочники C++. А этого достаточно, чтобы использовать C++ функции/классы в objective-c. Почитать можно например тут: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-in-an-ios-app-with-objective-c/

Comment: Файлы должны быть `mm`

Comment: @Unick А вы можете мне написать **1** - класс С++ с функцией которая что-нибудь возвращает (ну хотя бы int(x) { `return x+x;} ` **2** вызов этой функции из main в xcode? А то я пол-дня пытался что-нибудь нормальное написать и кучу ошибок возвращает компилятор

Comment: Добавьте ваш пример и лог ошибок и я постараюсь помочь.